# RSelenium - can't get started in R

Tags: r, macos, rselenium

I've been struggling for ages trying to resolve this and rather lost so would really appreciate your help.

I am trying to scrape a Javascript page through RStudio on a Mac and not even getting started which is frustrating.

1. I installed phantomjs through the brew command in Terminal
2. I installed a standalone selenium server through brew in Terminal
3. As soon as I run the checkForServer (or RSelenium::checkForServer) I get:

   Warning message:
   In order(as.numeric(gsub("(.*)/.*", "\1", selJAR)), decreasing = TRUE) :
   NAs introduced by coercion

Any ideas?

Comment: `checkForServer` and `startServer` are deprecated. The recommended way to run a Selenium Server with RSelenium is via Docker containers see http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker

Comment: Thanks for the thought but it seems to be for Windows and Linux and I'm on a Mac. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can install Docker for Mac or Docker toolbox see https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/. Docker for Mac is analogous to running Docker in Linux. Docker toolbox is analogous to running Docker in Windows as per the linked vignette.

Comment: Thank you! It now works a treat.